# Extending java configuration in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I m newbie on the spring and I m just testing some utilities to learn java configuration on the spring framework,so question is

I have two configuration as seen below and I want to extend one configuration to another and use sub java configuration with appconfig so I did this way and working everything good but I m still feeling its not good approach for me ,could you give me correct way on this or alternative of this thanks

Hibernate Configuration

```
**package configuration**
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"configuration"})
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;


    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(generateDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"whateverpackage.model"});
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(generateProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }



    @Bean
    public DataSource generateDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverclassname"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    public Properties generateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        return properties;

    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory); //constructor-arg can be use in xml
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

SubConfiguration

```
package another.configuration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"another.configuration"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
public class SubConfiguration extends HibernateConfiguration{

}
```

AppConfig

```
package another.configuration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="root package")
@Import(SubConfiguration.class)
public class AppConfig   {

}
```

Comment: in my personal view import should do fine, because it causes less hassle. 'inheritance' has scared and troubled people enough who use OOP languages.

Comment: thanks for your comment.